# Mirroring 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, mirror

Hi I'm trying to make a code that takes a 2d array and mirrors it like so,

```
input:        and get the output like so:  
  123                                      321
  456                                      654
  789                                      987
```

I have this portion of the code:

```
public static void mirror(Object[][] theArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < (theArray.length/2); i++) {
        Object[] temp = theArray[i];
        theArray[i] = theArray[theArray.length - i - 1];
        theArray[theArray.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

My program works however it's returning the opposite which is this

```
input:        and get the output like so:  
  123                                      789
  456                                      456
  789                                      123
```

What am I doing wrong..?

Comment: You're reversing the first dimension of the array, not the second. You need to wrap the `for` loop in `mirror` in another for loop, and adjust the indexes appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reversing the first dimension of the array (the 'rows'), not the second (the 'columns').

You need to wrap the for loop in mirror in another for loop, and adjust the indexes appropriately.

```
public static void mirror(Object[][] theArray) {
  for (int j = 0; j < theArray.length; ++j) {  // Extra for loop to go through each row in turn, performing the reversal within that row.
    Object[] row = theArray[j];
    for(int i = 0; i < (row.length/2); i++) {
        Object temp = row[i];
        row[i] = theArray[j][row.length - i - 1];
        row[row.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use contravariant array types like this. Read Effective Java 2nd Ed Item 25, "Prefer lists to arrays", for an account of how easy it is to break things like this.

Comment: should it not be "int j = 0; j < theArray.length; ++j"? And what's going on with "Object[] temp = row[i]; "? you would get an error.

Comment: Fixed. That'll teach me to try to wing code in the answer window.